# CakePHP 2.x - Persistent virtual fields issue

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.x

I have a brainteaser about virtual fields on associated models. I know it has it's limitations as you can read here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html#limitations-of-virtualfields. 
But in my specific case, I can't apply the theory of passing the virtualField property from one model to another (even when I read this topic: [Using virtual fields in cakePHP 2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630819/using-virtual-fields-in-cakephp-2-x)).

I'll try to explane my case as clear as possible.

## Database info

I have 3 tables to make a navigation on my website:

**menus**

- id
- name

**pages**

- id
- title
- content

**menu_page_links**

- id
- menu_id
- page_id
- title
- lft
- rgt
- plugin
- controller
- action

One page can be added to multiple menus, that's why I've made a link table (`MenuPageLink`) between menus and pages.

## Application info

### Menu model

```
class Menu extends AppModel
{
    public $hasMany = array(
        'MenuPageLink' => array(
            'className' => 'MenuPageLink',
            'foreignKey' => 'menu_id'
        )
    );
}
```

### Page model

```
class Page extends AppModel
{
    public $hasMany = array(
        'MenuPageLink' => array(
            'className' => 'MenuPageLink',
            'foreignKey' => 'page_id'
        )
    );
}
```

### MenuPageLink model

```
class MenuPageLink extends AppModel
{
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Menu',
        'Page'
    );

    // to calculate the depth of every menu page link

    public $virtualFields = array(
        'depth' => 'COUNT(MenuPageLink.title) - 1'
    );
}
```

### AppController

Now in my application, I want to load a specific menu on every page, e.g. the "Primary menu" from the "menus" table.
So in AppController.php, I referred to the tree needed models (`'Menu'`, `'Page'` and `'MenuPageLink'`) as following:

```
public $uses = array(
    'Menu',
    'Page',
    'MenuPageLink'
);
```

Then I get my menu pages that belongs to my specific menu with id "2":

```
$menu = $this->MenuPageLink->find('all', array(
    'fields' => array(
        'MenuPageLink.id',
        'MenuPageLink.title',
        'MenuPageLink.plugin',
        'MenuPageLink.controller',
        'MenuPageLink.action',
        'MenuPageLink.depth'
    ),
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => $this->MenuPageLink->table,
            'alias' => 'Parent',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => array(
                'MenuPageLink.lft BETWEEN Parent.lft AND Parent.rgt',
                'MenuPageLink.menu_id' => 1
            )
        )
    ),
    'conditions' => array(
        'MenuPageLink.menu_id' => 2,
        'MenuPageLink.lft >' => 1,
        'MenuPageLink.deleted' => null
    ),
    'group' => 'MenuPageLink.id',
    'order' => array(
        'MenuPageLink.lft ASC'
    )
));
```

This is my result when I debug my `$menu` variable:

```
array(
(int) 0 => array( 'MenuPageLink' => array( 'id' => '36', 'title' => 'Home', 'plugin' => '', 'controller' => 'home', 'action' => 'index', 'depth' => '1' ) ),
(int) 1 => array( 'MenuPageLink' => array( 'id' => '39', 'title' => 'News', 'plugin' => '', 'controller' => 'news_articles', 'action' => 'index', 'depth' => '1' ) ),
(int) 2 => array( 'MenuPageLink' => array( 'id' => '37', 'title' => 'About the park', 'plugin' => '', 'controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'view', 'depth' => '1' ) ),
(int) 3 => array( 'MenuPageLink' => array( 'id' => '41', 'title' => 'Attractions', 'plugin' => '', 'controller' => 'attractions', 'action' => 'index', 'depth' => '2' ) ),
(int) 4 => array( 'MenuPageLink' => array( 'id' => '42', 'title' => 'Animals', 'plugin' => '', 'controller' => 'animals', 'action' => 'index', 'depth' => '2' ) ),
(int) 5 => array( 'MenuPageLink' => array( 'id' => '43', 'title' => 'Events', 'plugin' => '', 'controller' => 'events', 'action' => 'index', 'depth' => '2' ) ),
(int) 6 => array( 'MenuPageLink' => array( 'id' => '44', 'title' => 'Shows', 'plugin' => '', 'controller' => 'shows', 'action' => 'index', 'depth' => '2' ) ),
(int) 7 => array( 'MenuPageLink' => array( 'id' => '45', 'title' => 'History', 'plugin' => '', 'controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'history', 'depth' => '2' ) ),
(int) 8 => array( 'MenuPageLink' => array( 'id' => '38', 'title' => 'Info', 'plugin' => '', 'controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'view2', 'depth' => '1' ) ),
(int) 9 => array( 'MenuPageLink' => array( 'id' => '40', 'title' => 'Media', 'plugin' => '', 'controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'media', 'depth' => '1' ) )
)
```

So far so good!

## What I'm trying

And here comes my problem. I only want to select the pages where depth = 1. I tried to make a new `'conditions'` parameter:

```
$menu = $this->MenuPageLink->find('all', array(
    'fields' => array(
        'MenuPageLink.id',
        'MenuPageLink.title',
        'MenuPageLink.plugin',
        'MenuPageLink.controller',
        'MenuPageLink.action',
        'MenuPageLink.depth'
    ),
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => $this->MenuPageLink->table,
            'alias' => 'Parent',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => array(
                'MenuPageLink.lft BETWEEN Parent.lft AND Parent.rgt',
                'MenuPageLink.menu_id' => 1
            )
        )
    ),
    'conditions' => array(
        'MenuPageLink.menu_id' => 2,
        'MenuPageLink.lft >' => 1,
        'MenuPageLink.deleted' => null,
        'MenuPageLink.depth' => 1 // <-- new rule in my query
    ),
    'group' => 'MenuPageLink.id',
    'order' => array(
        'MenuPageLink.lft ASC'
    )
));
```

and after a lot of headaches to make this work, I even tried to use the `Model::query()` method:

```
$this->MenuPageLink->query(
    "SELECT
        `MenuPageLink`.`id`
        , `MenuPageLink`.`title`
        , `MenuPageLink`.`lft`
        , `MenuPageLink`.`rgt`
        , `MenuPageLink`.`show`
        , `MenuPageLink`.`deleted`
        , (COUNT(`MenuPageLink`.`title`) - 1) AS `MenuPageLink`.`depth`
    FROM
        `blwfun`.`menu_page_links` AS `MenuPageLink`
    LEFT JOIN
        `blwfun`.`menus` AS `Menu`
    ON
        (`MenuPageLink`.`menu_id` = `Menu`.`id`)
    LEFT JOIN
        `blwfun`.`pages` AS `Page`
    ON
        (`MenuPageLink`.`page_id` = `Page`.`id`)
    LEFT JOIN
        `blwfun`.`menu_page_links` AS `Parent`
    ON
        (`MenuPageLink`.`lft` BETWEEN `Parent`.`lft` AND `Parent`.`rgt` AND `MenuPageLink`.`menu_id` = 1)
    WHERE
        `Parent`.`menu_id` = 1 AND `MenuPageLink`.`lft` > 1 AND `MenuPageLink`.`deleted` IS NULL AND `MenuPageLink`.`depth` = 1
    GROUP BY
        `MenuPageLink`.`id`
    ORDER BY
        `MenuPageLink`.`lft` ASC"
));
```

I keep getting the sql error, but I don't know how to solve it. As I said, I don't know how to apply the theory in de CakePHP docs (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html#limitations-of-virtualfields) to my specific case.
Is there anybody who can help me out with this please?

You would be a hero to me :)

Comment: 1) Whenever you have a SQL error, you need to share it. 2) Looking at your code, the problem is you have an aggregate function in your WHERE clause. You need to move `MenuPageLink.depth = 1` to a HAVING clause

Comment: AgRizzo, thx, it was the best answer I could imagine!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to AgRizzo, I changed my select query to this and it works fine:

```
$menuLinks = $this->MenuPageLink->find('all', array(
    'fields' => array(
        'MenuPageLink.id',
        'MenuPageLink.title',
        'MenuPageLink.lft',
        'MenuPageLink.rgt',
        'MenuPageLink.plugin',
        'MenuPageLink.controller',
        'MenuPageLink.action',
        'MenuPageLink.show',
        'MenuPageLink.depth',
        'MenuPageLink.deleted'
    ),
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => $this->MenuPageLink->table,
            'alias' => 'Parent',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => array(
                'MenuPageLink.lft BETWEEN Parent.lft AND Parent.rgt',
                'MenuPageLink.menu_id' => 1
            )
        )
    ),
    'conditions' => array(
        'Parent.menu_id' => 1,
        'MenuPageLink.lft >' => 1,
        'MenuPageLink.deleted' => null
    ),
    'group' => 'MenuPageLink.id HAVING (COUNT(MenuPageLink.title) - 1) <= 1',
    'order' => array(
        'MenuPageLink.lft ASC'
    )
));
```

I hope it can help people with the same virtual field problem ;)